# Zod and conditional validation

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I have a form which use React Hook Form and Zod as validator.

I have to validate some fields if the `Committente` type is `Privato` and some others if is `Azienda` (Let's just ignore `Azienda Estera`)

For `Privato` type I have those fields:

- Nome
- Cognome
- Indirizzo
- CAP
- Città
- Prov
- Stato
- Codice Fiscale
- Email
- Telefono

while for `Azienda` those others:

- Nome Azienda
- Indirizzo
- CAP
- Città
- Prov
- Stato
- Partita IVA
- Email
- Telefono

So, basically, the fields `Nome`, `Cognome`, and `Codice Fiscale` are undefined when `azienda` is selected and the fields `Nome Azienda` and `Partita Iva` are undefined when `privato` is selected.

How can I build this type of schema?

I tried something like this:

```js
const mySchema = z.union([
        z.object({
            tipologia: z.literal("privato"),
            nome: z.string().min(1, { message: "Il nome è richiesto" }),
            cognome: z.string().min(1, { message: "Il cognome è richiesto" }),
            ...
        }),
        z.object({
            tipologia: z.literal("azienda"),
            nomeAzienda: z.string().min(5, { message: "Il nome è richiesto" }),
            ...
        }),
    ])
```

but didn't work.

[image: Committente private type]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it works using `discriminatedUnion` method. **Actually, while testing, I was just forgetting to implement the `invalid` and `error` message on the fields**, so I didn't have any feedbacks and I thought it doesn't work.

```js
// Base Schema
const baseSchema = z.object({
    indirizzo: z.string().min(3, { message: "L'indirizzo è richiesto" }),
    cap: z
        .string()
        ...
})

// Schema
const mySchema = z.discriminatedUnion("tipologia", [
        z
            .object({
                tipologia: z.literal("privato"),
                nome: z.string().min(1, { message: "Il nome è richiesto" }),
                cognome: z.string().min(1, { message: "Il cognome è richiesto" }),
                cf: z.string().min(16, { message: "Il Codice Fiscale è richiesto" }),
                stato: z.literal("Italia"),
            })
            .merge(baseSchema),
        z
            .object({
                tipologia: z.literal("azienda"),
                nomeAzienda: z.string().min(1, { message: "Il nome è richiesto" }),
                piva: z.string().min(11, { message: "La Partita IVA è richiesta" }),
                stato: z.literal("Italia"),
            })
            .merge(baseSchema),
        z
            .object({
                tipologia: z.literal("aziendaEstera"),
                nomeAzienda: z.string().min(1, { message: "Il nome è richiesto" }),
                piva: z.string().min(11, { message: "La Partita IVA è richiesta" }),
                stato: z.string().min(1, { message: "Indicare lo Stato" }),
            })
            .merge(baseSchema),
    ]),
```